# ¿Cómo solucionar este error al crear proyectos en Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular

Al intentar crear un proyecto en Angular me aparece un error. Intente actualizar la versión Angular a la mas estable (18) pensado que eso solucionaría el error, pero el error continua y no deja compilar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de poner "este error" en el título, pon el error en cuestión, tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta. El mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask].

Comment: Te falta hacer `npm install` para que se instalen todas las dependencias de tu proyecto.